# Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined

Tags: javascript

im a newbie in javascript and wanted to learn something, I've been wondering, i found this on https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors where i can use cors so i can access a google API like kissflow, i dont know if im in the right way. so here's the thing, im using the standalone Auth client that was described in the said site, but everytime i tried to run the program the error prompt
`Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined`

i just copied the code at the site which is

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
type="text/javascript">
</script>`<script type="text/javascript">`
//<![CDATA[gapi.load('auth', init);//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: You have to create init function then pass in to load method like this

    function init(){
        //do something
    }

Comment: ohh ok, how about loading directly using this https://apis.google.com/js/auth.js?onload=init
should i just put it in the script tag? like <script src="">?

Comment: yes it means when you call this api the onload method is working as a callback function

Comment: oohh, i tried using the direct load of standalone Auth client and get this kind of error `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').`
i think there's something wrong in my code, anyway, Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
  gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>"});
});
</script>
```

Make sure that you host this locally, and when creating the client ID, add the localhost URL with the port. Without a URL, the client ID will not send back a proper response, resulting in an error. Since the client ID doesn't support "file:///", you have to use a web hosting service or something, or the easier route, just download the latest python and set up a localhost server.

Latest python download: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Setting up the server: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server#running_a_simple_local_http_server

Note that sometimes you have to use "py" instead of "python" for reasons I am too lazy to research .

To actually initiate the login and use the API:

```
<script>
function authenticate() {
return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn({scope: ""/*Declare scopes with spaces in between, depends on API you're using*/})
  .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
  function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
}

function loadClient() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey("<YOUR_API_KEY>");
  return gapi.client.load(""/*Declare discovery document, depends on API you're using*/)
  .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
  function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
}

function execute() {
  return gapi.client.classroom.courses.list({}) //Used classroom courses list as an example, but use the apropriate API Fields, found in your method's "Overview" section on the API Documentation
  .then(function(response) {
    // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
    console.log("Response", response);
  },
  function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}

gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
  gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>"});
});

authenticate().then(loadClient).then(execute)
</script>
```

Note that sometimes you have to clear cache in order for this to work (I mean, worked for me), so if you have some trouble, try that.